# jQuery Mobile - How to show/hide div based on <select> element's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am really confused. I am trying to make multiple divs hide/show based on when a user selects their age.

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="page1">

<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="fcontain">
      <label for="selectmenu" class="select">Choose your age:</label>
      <select name="selectmenu" id="selectmenu">
        <option value="option1">Im over 21.</option>
        <option value="option2" id>Im under 21.</option>
      </select>
</div>
</div>

<div id="page2"> <!--If user selects "Im over 21."-->
  <p>Content for page 2 goes here...</p>

</div>

<div id="page3"> <!--If user selects "Im under 21."-->
  <p>Content for page 3 goes here...</p>
</div>

</div>
```

How can I go about doing this? I did not add more code because I think it is not that important. I just need some jquery/javascript code that would allow me to show/hide other divs. When a user selects any of the values above I want the corresponding div to show and hide the present containing div (#page1) not (#wrapper).

Thanks for your help!

Adan

Comment: its not a big deal, check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a0pw3119/86/

Comment: @Adan G which dive you want to show and hide ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to Show/Hide `div with id="page2"`

Then corresponding jQuery should be like:

```
$("#selectmenu").change(function () {
   $("#page2").fadeOut();
    if ($(this).val() == "option1") {
       $("#page2").fadeIn();
    }
});
```